# How procedure insert data using UDT?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-types

I am new to ASP.net and the concept of UDT in it. I used to work on PHP and so I am having difficulty in understanding the UDT concept.

This is the stored procedure written to insert data from input forms to the database(SQL Server).

The code is working fine and is written by senior developers in my company.

```
    CREATE Procedure [dbo].[Save_Supplier]
    @Supplier_UDT Supplier_UDT Readonly,
    @UserName varchar(80)
    AS
    Begin

    -------------Block 1------
    Declare @TP Table(ID int,Suppliercode varchar(80),Suppliername varchar(80),GSTVATNumber int,Description varchar(80),Productlist varchar(80),Bankdetails varchar(80),
    pymenttermdescription varchar(80),Currency int,Pendingpayement Varchar(80),pendingorders int,Active bit )

 -------------Block 2------
    Insert into @TP(ID ,Suppliercode ,Suppliername,GSTVATNumber,Description ,Productlist,Bankdetails,pymenttermdescription,Currency,Pendingpayement ,pendingorders ,Active)
    select ID ,Suppliercode ,Suppliername,GSTVATNumber,Description ,Productlist,Bankdetails,pymenttermdescription,Currency,Pendingpayement ,pendingorders ,Active from @Supplier_UDT

 -------------Block 3------
    Update Supplier
    set 
    Suppliercode=a.Suppliercode ,
    Suppliername=a.Suppliername
    ,GSTVATNumber=a.GSTVATNumber
    ,Description =a.Description
    ,Productlist=a.Productlist
    ,Bankdetails=a.Bankdetails
    ,pymenttermdescription=a.pymenttermdescription
    ,Currency=a.Currency
    ,Pendingpayement=a.Pendingpayement
     ,pendingorders=a.pendingorders 
     ,Active=a.Active
     from @TP a inner join Supplier
     on a.ID=Supplier.ID

 -------------Block 4------
     Insert into Supplier(Suppliercode ,Suppliername,GSTVATNumber,Description ,Productlist,Bankdetails,pymenttermdescription,Currency,Pendingpayement ,pendingorders ,Active)
     select Suppliercode ,Suppliername,GSTVATNumber,Description ,Productlist,Bankdetails,pymenttermdescription,Currency,Pendingpayement ,pendingorders ,Active
     from @TP where ID not in (select ID from Supplier) and Suppliercode!=''
```

Upto my understanding, Block 1 is simply declaration the structure of temporary table/variable. 
In Block 2, the the user passed input data in stored in the temporary table/variable.

I am having difficulty in understanding **Block 3** and **Block 4**

I don't understand what is the UPDATE query doing before the INSERT query?

What is the purpose of Block 3 and Block 4?

*(The code is working all fine, without errors.)*

Comment: We can't know the reasons for the business logic of your company. This is also off-topic for SO

Comment: Blocks 1/2 seem redundant as `@TP` can be substituted with `@Supplier_UDT`.  Block 3 updates the Supplier table with values from `@TP` with matching IDs, if `@TP` has IDs that were not in Supplier the last insert adds them as new rows.

Comment: There is no need for a table variable to hold the contents of your table valued parameter. You can just use the parameter like a table.

Comment: @SeanLange So you mean, I do not need to block1 and block2 , I can directly go on block3 by using the data received in Supplier_UDT

Comment: @AlexK.
This procedure is doing 2 task, modification if ID present and if not, adding new row! right!  
and what if, I only want the procedure to perform, UPDATE? How should I write it?

Comment: It is possible to perform both the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` using a single `MERGE` statement. The proc could be a single statement by eliminating the local table variable too.

Comment: Can anyone of you please help me out, writting a sample code, without @TP? Please. It needs to perform only UPDATE. I only need the correct syntax, Ill handle the conditions and other logistics later.

Comment: Just use your existing code in Blocks 3 and 4. But instead of @TP use your table parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[1] First thing I would like to notice about this source code isn't the usage of another table variable (`@TP`) but the **missing of transaction management** and also **missing of error handling**. There are at least two statements (last two: UPDATE and INSERT) under the risk of generating exceptions / errors at statement level (for example).

[2] I don't see any reason to use one more table variable (`@TP`), the first one being the parameter `@Supplier_UDT Supplier_UDT`. It'll create/increase [tempdb contention](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/the-accidental-dba-day-27-of-30-troubleshooting-tempdb-contention/) and from developer point of view will create another dependency (for example: if we are going to change data type of one of those columns within `dbo.Supplier` table then we'll have to update also this stored procedure and definition of `@TP` column.

[3] Note: both table variables (`@TP` and `@Supplier_UDT`) have the same columns or (at least) a set of common columns: `ID ,Suppliercode ,Suppliername,GSTVATNumber,Description ,Productlist,Bankdetails,pymenttermdescription,Currency,Pendingpayement ,pendingorders ,Active`. Isn't clear if data types, NULL-ability and constraints are the same.

[4] Block 3 & 4 seems to be an implementation of [UPSERT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)) *pattern* but for many rows (note: most of examples for UPSERT are using just one row). This means that for those suppliers that *already* exist in `dbo.Supplier` table (SQL schema should be mandatory) `UPDATE` statement will change/update following columns `SupplierCode, SupplierName, ...` with the *latest* values and new suppliers are `INSERT`ed into `dbo.Supplier` table.

As Dan Guzman already mentioned within his comment (+1), instead of these two statements (`UPDATE` and `INSERT`), a single `MERGE` statement could be used:

```
 MERGE dbo.Supplier WITH(HOLDLOCK) AS dst  -- Destination table
 USING @Supplier_UDT AS src ON dst.ID = src.ID -- Source table
 WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE
    SET 
    Suppliercode    = a.Suppliercode ,
    Suppliername    = a.Suppliername,
    GSTVATNumber    = a.GSTVATNumber,
    Description     = a.Description,
    Productlist     = a.Productlist,
    Bankdetails     = a.Bankdetails,
    pymenttermdescription = a.pymenttermdescription,
    Currency        = a.Currency,
    Pendingpayement = a.Pendingpayement,
    pendingorders   = a.pendingorders,
    Active          = a.Active
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND dst.Suppliercode != '' THEN -- Please make sure that Suppliercode refers to destination table and not to source table 
    INSERT (Suppliercode ,Suppliername,GSTVATNumber,Description ,Productlist,Bankdetails,pymenttermdescription,Currency,Pendingpayement ,pendingorders ,Active)
    VALUES (Suppliercode ,Suppliername,GSTVATNumber,Description ,Productlist,Bankdetails,pymenttermdescription,Currency,Pendingpayement ,pendingorders ,Active);
```

[5] Why I would use `HOLDLOCK` table hint ? See Dan Guzman's blog: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx

[6] Also, there are some bugs regarding MERGE statement described here:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Some of them are more or less *serious*.

[7] [`If it ain't broke, don't fix it`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:If_it_ain%27t_broke,_don%27t_fix_it)

Comment: Wow, That was an amazing guidance. Thanks alot. And thanks for the procedure, Ill reference to create new procedures :)